# Send a key without having to release shift + alt

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having a difficult time trying to code this idea. I want to send <kbd>E</kbd> 5 times while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>. After it is send 5 times I want to send <kbd>E</kbd> again another five times without having to let go of <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: Probably a combination of a `loop`, `hotstring`, and `send`. What have you tried?

Comment: In other words, you want to send E 10 times. Or do you mean send 5 times, pause, send 5 times? Or do you mean, while holding Shift and Alt, send 5 times each time a third button is used? Need more information please!